# displays a lot of data using like codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I use this code to display data according to the user who is logged in, and display their data. 
but with this syntax the data that appears does not match the defined data, and also other user data sometimes appears too.

```
$id=$this->session->userdata('ses_id');

    $this->db->SELECT('*');
    $this->db->from('doc_priv_std');

    $this->db->join('acc',' doc_priv_std.id_acc=acc.id_acc');

    $this->db->where('doc_priv_std.id_acc ',$id,('and 
    type_doc LIKE "%.doc%" 
    or "%.docx%" 
    or "%.pdf" 
    or "%.xls%" 
    or "%.xlsx%" 
    or "%.ppt%" 
    or "%.pptx%" 
    or "%.zip%" 
    or "%.rar%"'));

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
```

please help so that the data that appears as defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong - you can't do this with your way - you have to organise your Query properly - try the following

```
$id=$this->session->userdata('ses_id');

$arrExtension = ['.docx', '.pdf', '.xls', '.xlsx', '.ppt', '.pptx', '.zip', '.rar'];

$this->db
    ->select('*')
    ->from('doc_priv_std')
    ->join('acc',' doc_priv_std.id_acc=acc.id_acc')
    ->where('acc.id_acc', $id)
    ->group_start();

foreach($arrExtension AS $strExtension)
{
    $this->db->or_like('type_doc', $strExtension);
}
$query = $this->db->group_end()->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `var_dump($this->db->last_query());` before your return to see the db query you are actually running to help with debugging, but it could be that you where statement is wrong? Try this instead:

```
$where = 'WHERE type_doc LIKE "%.doc%" 
or "%.docx%" 
or "%.pdf" 
or "%.xls%" 
or "%.xlsx%" 
or "%.ppt%" 
or "%.pptx%" 
or "%.zip%" 
or "%.rar%"';

$this->db->select('*')
    ->join('acc',' doc_priv_std.id_acc=acc.id_acc')
    ->where('doc_priv_std.id_acc', $id)
    ->where($where);
$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->num_rows() > 0 ? $query->result_array() : FALSE;
```